# Live calculation on jquery change

Tags: jquery

We are using following fields to do some calculation.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.num').blur(function () {
var amount    = parseInt($('#amount').val()) || 0;
var openbal = parseInt($('#openbal').val());
var disc    = parseInt($('#disc').val());
var netpay  = fees+openbal-disc || 0;
$('#netpay').val(netpay);
});
});
```

And here is html code

```
 <select name="product" class="product">
   <option selected>Select product</option>
   <option>Product1</option>
   <option>Product2</option>
 </select>
<input type="text" size="30" name="amount" class="num" id="amount" />
<input type="text" class="num" name="openbal" value="0" id="openbal" />
<input type="text" class="num" name="disc" value="0" id="disc" />
<input type="text" name="netpay" id="netpay" />
```

So What we are doing here is...

1. Select product from drop down list and fetch amount(#amount) using ajax.
2. We are doing calculation using `.num(class)` like given discount or any pending balance.

Our code is working fine, but it only updates netpay(#netpay) when we blur on any .num field and it updates calculation. But we would like to do calculation after amount receives its value and even should update netpay(#netpay) if we updates any of num(.num) field, for example we give discount(#disc) 500, so netpay(#netpay) should be updated.

thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to **raise the `blur` event** once you set the value for `#amount`.

So in your `success` handler for the Ajax call, do something like:

```
$('#amount').val('newValue').blur();
```

As the `blur` event handler is also bound to `#amount`, raising the event will execute it (but you could use any other element the handler is bound to).

---

Unfortunately, setting the value of a text input element with `.val()` does **not** raise the `change` event.

---

**Further remarks:**

If you use `parseInt`, make sure you pass the right radix as second parameter. So it should be `parseInt($('#amount').val(), 10)`. Otherwise, if someone inputs a number with leading 0s, the value is parsed as octal value. If the values are plain numbers without any suffix, you can also parse the string as number by just prepending `+`:

```
var amount = +$('#amount').val() || 0,
    openbal = +$('#openbal').val() || 0,
    disc  = +$('#disc').val() || 0,
    netpay  = fees + openbal - disc;
$('#netpay').val(netpay);
```

Comment: yes,thanks. Can you tell me about parseInt more, so i should write parseInt($('#amount').val(), 10) instead of parseInt($('#amount').val());

Comment: thanks for your great help, and can you help me with 1 more code, thats making little bit problem. It's about for loop

Comment: @seoppc: Regarding `parseInt`, have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt. What `for` loop are you talking about? And if it solved your problem, you should mark this answer as accepted ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that it doesn't update as you are typing into the num inputs?

Consider separating your calculation function out and calling it from different events.

```
function doCalc() {
    var fees    = 0; // <-- is undefined in your example
    var amount  = parseInt($('#amount').val()) || 0;
    var openbal = parseInt($('#openbal').val());
    var disc    = parseInt($('#disc').val());
    var netpay  = fees + openbal - disc || 0;
    $('#netpay').val(netpay); // <-- the result is not going anywhere
}

$(function(){
    $('.num')
        .blur(doCalc) // keeping your original event
        .keydown(doCalc) // also updating as they type
        .change(doCalc) // also update if value changes
        ;
});
```

I didn't test this. I'm guessing whether this is what you're after.

Comment: thanks for your answer, we would like to get #netpay updates in 2 cases, when #amount get its value(using ajax) and if any of .num get value. I hope you got idea. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

`$('#amount').blur(function ()`

instead of this:

```
 $('.num').blur(function ()
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but how netpay(#netpay) would be updated if we don't give blur function to .num

Comment: from your code, the textbox with id of (#amount) already has the num class, so it's the same :)

Comment: its working the same as before, we have to click on any text field(with class of .num) to get live results in #netpay, is it possible to update #netpay when #amount gets its value and even then when we change .num value.

Comment: the answer posted by @Parched Squid is the same that I was about to write, either you are not make it very clear for us to help you, or you couldn't get his answer to work.

Comment: The only difference is that the event handler is only bound to `#amount` and not all of the `.num`s. So this would not help.