# How to make a PHP calculator using input from an HTML-Form but to make it give me instant results?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, jquery

I wanted to create a calculator just for the sake of coding in php. Here is the result: [PHPTest](http://php.horyzon.de)

Sorry that some is in German.

**Code**:

```
<?php
    $umsatz = $_POST['umsatz'];
    $varkost = $_POST['varkost'];
    $fixkost = $_POST['fixkost'];
    $capitalassets = $_POST['capitalassets'];
    $inventories = $_POST['inventories'];
    $claims = $_POST['claims'];

    $ebit = $umsatz - $varkost - $fixkost;
    $umsatzrendite = $ebit / $umsatz;

    $capitalemployed = $capitalassets + $inventories + $claims;
    $kapitalumschlag = $umsatz/$capitalemployed;

    $roce = $umsatzrendite * $kapitalumschlag;  
?>


<h1>Berechnung des ROCE</h1>

<p>Und der Return on the Capital Employed für die eingegebenen Daten beträgt <strong><?php echo round($roce, 2) ?>%</strong>.</p>

<p>Das Ergebnis basiert auf einer Umsatzrendite von <strong><?php echo round($umsatzrendite*100, 2) ?>%</strong>, einem Capital Employed von <strong><?php echo $capitalemployed ?></strong> und einem Kapitalumschlag von <strong><?php echo round($kapitalumschlag, 2) ?></strong>. <br />
<br />
Das Ebit beträgt <strong><?php echo $ebit ?></strong></p>
```

But it is not how I would like it to be.

I would very much prefer, to be able to insert the the necessary values into a form and get an instant result for it, instead of having to push the "submit" button. Then being linked to another php-Site, where the actual calculation starts.

I have the feeling that PHP might be the wrong language for what I have in mind. Can someone point me into the direction, to get this done? Is PHP the solution for this? Or Ajax or pure JS?

I don't know but I would most kindly appreciate a good hint.

Comment: This can easily be done in pure JS.

Comment: I don't understand why not to use only JS, but if you have your reasons use AJAX

Comment: Asynchronous JavaScript And XML without Javascript.. Anyway, I don't see OP saying he doesn't want to use JS?

Comment: Using pure JS also has the invaluable advantage of running the calculations on the client's computer, as opposed to your own, expensive server time.

Comment: One note that could be important for you. You write `kapitalumschlag` so i assume your calculations have to be correct. If you do e.g. `1.1 + 0.03` this is not decimal calculation like you would probably expect but floating point so depending on the implementation the result is e.g. `1.1300000000000001`, if you do this the wrong way your results (if you have some sums) could be wrong (sometimes it is ok but it could result in errors of `0.1` if done the wrong way, which in some situations is a to big error especially with finance)

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. Yes. I don't mind using JS. Just thought that php would be good too... and I am not that good in JS yet... but I guess I have to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily done with JS alone. No need to do this server-side at all.

To point you in a direction:

Use JS to detect when your input fields are changed.

On change calculate all available values to generate a result if possible, and show them.

Here is an example: [Live calculation on jquery change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456929/live-calculation-on-jquery-change) and another [Jquery - Auto calculate input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13601697/jquery-auto-calculate-input-field)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look into it. Just needed a direction. I just wanted to "learn" php, also because I thought, that later on I could save the variables into a database. But I guess that can be done later anyway.